# How to remove a window / navigator JS API for unit testing?

Tags: javascript, testing, web

I'd like to test the behaviour of a library when an API doesn't exist in a browser.

For example if I have the following check:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator &&
'PushManager' in window &&
'Notification' in window &&
'showNotification' in ServiceWorkerRegistration.prototype) {
   // Do something
} else {
   throw new Error('Catch in test');
}
```

Is it possible to completely remove properties on these global scopes?

Comment: Pass them in your code as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to completely remove properties on these global scopes?

Not as far as I know. One solution is to make the code independent of the global scope.

Wrap this feature check in a function taking these object primitives in as parameters, then mock them in your test.

```js
function initServiceWorker(window, navigator) {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator &&
    'PushManager' in window &&
    'Notification' in window &&
    'showNotification' in ServiceWorkerRegistration.prototype) {
    // Do something
  } else {
    throw new Error('Catch in test');
  }
}

initServiceWorker(window, navigator)
alert("first test passed")
initServiceWorker(window, {})
```